# Help on \Tree diagram by using tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat

Tags: tikz-trees

My desired out is:

[image]

I've tried as:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}%
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%\toprule%[-12pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}\label{bicycletree}
%\tikzset{level distance = 25pt}
\Tree[.DP [.D [.D ] [.Agr$^D$ $[+$m$+$h$+$pl$]$ ] ] [.NumP [.Num [.n$_j$ [.\node(id3){$v_i$}; \node(id2){$\surd$BOY}; ] [.n $+m,+h$ ] ] [.Num $[+]$pl ] ] [.nP [.n$_j$ ] [.\node(id1){v$_i$}; ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick,<->] (id2)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5)..(id1);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\vspace{-38pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

How can I meet the output as in first image? Please suggest....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the space is the position of the control points, `+(south west:5) and +(south:5)`. Move them up, by reducing the distance in those polar coordinates, e.g. `+(south west:2.5) and +(south:3)`.

One way of adding the additional arrow is to add a coordinate along the first arrow, and draw the second arrow from that. I used just trial and error to find an appropriate value for `pos`.

Finally, for the vertical alignment, add `baseline` to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{gb4e}%
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%\toprule%[-12pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\label{bicycletree}
%\tikzset{level distance = 25pt}
\Tree[.DP [.D [.D ] [.Agr$^D$ $[+$m$+$h$+$pl$]$ ] ] [.NumP [.Num [.n$_j$ [.\node(id3){$v_i$}; \node(id2){$\surd$BOY}; ] [.n $+m,+h$ ] ] [.Num $[+]$pl ] ] [.nP [.n$_j$ ] [.\node(id1){v$_i$}; ] ] ] ]
\draw[semithick,<->] (id2)..controls +(south west:2.5) and +(south:3)..(id1) coordinate [pos=0.17] (tmp);
\draw [->, semithick] ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]tmp) to[bend left=40] (id3);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\vspace{-38pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow....such a quick answer...It works like a champ...Thanks a lot....